# Visual Studio not recognizing file after changing from erroneous extension

Tags: visual-studio

I've been struggling with this for a couple of hours and then I just fixed that.

Problem is, when I was creating another `.cpp` file I misspelled the extension with `.cp` and then I immediately changed that file back to `.cpp` with Visual Studio's *rename file* feature.

The linking just stopped working after that. It was saying to me that i have unresolved external. My `.h` file couldn't be linked with that `.cpp` file which I renamed from `.cp`.

Somehow, when I created the file with a wrong extension, VS remembered that and even after renaming that file back to the correct extension, it still didn't recognize it.

I fixed my problem by just creating a new `.cpp` file (this time without an error), and everything just started working.

Has anyone experienced that before? Someone probably knows but I have not found anything related to this problem yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you acidentaly typed wrong extension when creating C++ file then to make VS treat it as C++ file you should right click on the file item in Solution Explorer, open `Properties` dialog and change `Item type` on `General` tab from `does not participate in build` to `C++ compiler` (or to `C++ header` if it suppose to be a header file).

Comment: Yes. Interesting why Visual Studio doesn't do that for you implicitly because it would make sense i guess.

Comment: @Richard I don't think I would want VS to change the compiler type I've set up just because I change the extension.